# Unix shell script for reading through files in a directory and moving them to respective folders

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting, but please help me with the problem below.

I have many log files under a directory. I have to read all the files under that directory and create folders month wise and move them to respective month folders. Also, if a file/directory is older than 12 months I should delete it.

I have file names in this format : `S20130803.123`     I have to read 201308 from that file name and create a folder if one is not available and move that file into it.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: What have you done so far? It is a broad problem that can be solved in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the "year-month" part with plain bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
filename=S20130803.123
month=${filename:1:6}
echo $month              # 201308
```

To compare with 12 months ago:

```
yearago=$( date -d "last year" +%Y%m )
if [[ $month < $yearago ]]; then ...
```

When creating a directory, use `mkdir -p` -- the -p option will suppress the error if the dir already exists.